# Unable to setState inside child component using the value passed by Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, setstate

I am having this situation where I am implementing a Pagination component to which I am passing the length from the parent component. I am unable to print the page numbers in this child component. It is throwing "Maximum depth reached"

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-benz-kfn9q

Can someone help me here?

### Parent

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";

import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      length: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ length: 99 });
  }

  render() {
    return <Pagination dataCount={this.state.length} />;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### Child

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class Pagination extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  renderPageNumbers = () => {
    const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.props.dataCount / 10);
    let pages = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
      pages.push(<span key={i}>{i}</span>);
    }
    this.setState({ pages });
  };

  render() {
    return <>{this.renderPageNumbers()}</>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return pages from `renderPageNumbers` function. For example,

```
renderPageNumbers = () => {
    const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.props.dataCount / 2);
    let pages = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
      pages.push(<span key={i}>{i}</span>);
    }
    return pages;
    // this.setState({ pages });
  };
```

**CodeSanbox link is listed [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigorous-dream-uulnw)**

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: It worked, What if I want to store this "numberOfPages" in a state property  say "pageCount" , Where would I do that? Check my sandbox for Pagination Component, for displaying Prev and Next

Comment: @vrosario do you want to store these page counts in your pagination component?

Comment: Yes Check the sandbox once :) For the sake of displaying "Previous" and "Next" links I want to store

Comment: @vrosario you can set in `componentDidMount`

Comment: @vrosario I would suggest you to go through https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination

https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/pagination-in-reactjs-36f4a6a6eb43

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/pagination/

Comment: The value (pages) is not getting set inside componentDidMount with the sandbox you have provided

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pages: this.findNumberOfPages()
    };
    this.findNumberOfPages = this.findNumberOfPages.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.dataCount != this.props.dataCount){
      this.setState({ pages: this.findNumberOfPages() });
    }
  }

  findNumberOfPages() {
    return Math.ceil(this.props.dataCount / 10);
  }

  renderPageNumbers = () => {
    const numberOfPages = this.findNumberOfPages()
    let pages = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
      pages.push(<span key={i}>{i}</span>);
    }
    return pages;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.currentPage > 1 ? <span>Prev</span> : ""}
        {this.renderPageNumbers()}
        {this.props.currentPage < this.state.pages ? <span>Next</span> : ""}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why Math.ceil(this.props.dataCount / 10) in two places? Also I did not understand the code inside  componentDidUpdate()?

Comment: That you can call the same function. In componentDidUpdate, We are checking whether the data count is changed. And if data count is changed then our pages state has to be updated right? Hope I was clear enough.